# SQL Query Create Table Error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, ddl, create-table

I got this error message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
>   full_name varchar,
>   first_name varchar,
>   last_name varchar,
>   email va' at line 2

```
create table ABC_CAFE(
    fb_id varchar NOT NULL,
    full_name varchar,
    first_name varchar,
    last_name varchar,
    email varchar,
    gender varchar,
    age_range varchar,
    link varchar,
    locale varchar,
    updated_time varchar,
    timezone varchar,
    verified varchar,
    url varchar,
    date_time varchar NOT NULL,
    device varchar,
    device_brand varchar,
    operating_system varchar,
    browser_name varchar,
    CONSTRAINT ID_DATE_TIME_KEY PRIMARY KEY (fb_id,date_time)
);
```

Comment: What SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provide column size for the `varchar` like `varchar(50)`

Working SQL fiddle after adding the column size: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a06419

---

**Edit:**

For sample I added `varchar(50)`, you can increase/reduce the column size according to each column's requirement.

Comment: The number in parethesis indicates the max length of the string that can be put in the column

Comment: Thanks. Solved after add in number for varchar.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify a length when you define a `varchar` column. E.g.:

```
create table ABC_CAFE(
    fb_id varchar(10) NOT NULL, -- E.g., here
    full_name varchar(10),
    first_name varchar(10),
    last_name varchar(10),
    email varchar(10),
    gender varchar(10),
    age_range varchar(10),
    link varchar(10),
    locale varchar(10),
    updated_time varchar(10),
    timezone varchar(10),
    verified varchar(10),
    url varchar(10),
    date_time varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    device varchar(10),
    device_brand varchar(10),
    operating_system varchar(10),
    browser_name varchar(10),
    CONSTRAINT ID_DATE_TIME_KEY PRIMARY KEY (fb_id, date_time)
)
```

Comment: You should probably add that this is just an example, and `(10)` would not necessarily be sufficient for some of these lines.

Comment: Thanks. Solved after add in number for varchar.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the length of varchar filed like varchar(20)

Comment: Thanks. Solved after add in number for varchar.

Answer (score 0):

Varchar requires you to specify the length of the string.

ie.

`full_name varchar(10)`

Would specify the full_name column to contain a maximum of 10 characters.